# Monitoring All Logic Apps in a Resource Group with one Alert

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

We have more than 40 logic apps and what we would like to do is Monitor Logic Apps for TRIGGER FAILURES and whenever the logic app fails to execute we would like to send an email to our support team. Unfortunately the only way I have seen in Microsoft documentation is by selecting individual Logic App and then configuring the Alert for it, but doing this for 40 Logic Apps across 4 environments is going to be cumbersome and also redundant, so wanted to know if we can create one single ALERT for TRIGGER FAILURES of All Logic Apps within a Resource Group?

If this is not possible do we get any logs of Trigger Failures of Logic App being logged somewhere in AzureDiagnostics (Azure Monitor) which we can query using KQL?

Apprecaite your help.
Thank you
K

Comment: Hi @user42012, You may also try using Serverless360 which gives deep integrated tooling to diagnose your Azure Logic Apps which is specially built for the Azure support team. Nevertheless, your above challenge can be easily addressed using the tool, no matter if the logic app is from other resource group, region etc.

Comment: Thanks but seems its paid product and log Analytics servers the purpose easily without any licensing fees. Plus my issue is resolved with a simple query. @NadeemAhmed. And I just realized you are trying to market your own product Nadeem, when an easy out of the box solution is available for free. Thanks but no thanks for using it. Customer are happy with out of the box soln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that since we have enabled the Diagnostics logging for Azure Logic App, everything is reported into Azure Log Analytics workspace and I can simply use the following query for creating a  custom Alert and whenever the count is > 0, this will cover all logic apps within a resource group:

AzureMetrics
| where Resource contains "MY RESOURCE GROUPNAME" and MetricName contains "RunsFailed" and Total >= 1  and ResourceProvider contains "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"

Using above query I can get all failure of Logic apps within a resource group.