# azure logic app for failed connections and slow running queries to send the mail automatically

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

can anyone suggest how to  create the logic app for failed connections in azure to send mail automatically, diagnostics setting in logs log analytics enabled, for failed connection need how many failed connections with username and ip address.

```
AzureDiagnostics

| where event_class_s == "connection_log"

and event_subclass_s == "DISCONNECT"
```

also need to automate through logic app for slow running queries any suggestions.

need to run from Azure log analytics and send mail through logic app.

Comment: Hey @singh, had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You can enable Log Analytics when you create your logic app or install the Logic Apps Management solution in your Log Analytics workspace for existing logic apps to enable logging for your logic app. This solution gathers data for your logic app runs and offers particular details like status, execution time, resubmission status, and correlation IDs. Then, to enable logging and query creation for this data.

for complete setup please refer this [**`Microsoft Documentation|Set up Azure Monitor logs and collect diagnostics data for Azure Logic Apps`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics)

To get the all failure status of logic app you can use the below query as well

```
AzureMetrics | where Resource contains "MY RESOURCE GROUPNAME" and MetricName contains "RunsFailed" and Total >= 1 and ResourceProvider contains "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"
```

[***Source|SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003065/monitoring-all-logic-apps-in-a-resource-group-with-one-alert)